# Python SyntaxError: invalid syntax, are brackets allowed in function parameters in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

The function works in python2:

```
def setCellValue(self, (x, y), value):
    self.map[x][y] = value
```

But when I'm trying in python3 it shows invalid syntax:

```
def setCellValue(self, (x, y), value):
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is it the bracket problem? How can I fix this in py3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, tuple unpacking was removed in python3. According to [PEP 3113](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/):

> The example function at the beginning of this PEP could easily be
> rewritten as:
>
> ```
> def fxn(a, b_c, d):
>     b, c = b_c
>     pass
> ```
>
> and in no way lose functionality.

It's existence served only to complicate the grammar and bytecode generation, so it was removed.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, that feature got taken out in Python 3. It didn't play well with signature inspection. You have to unpack the argument yourself:

```
def setCellValue(self, pos, value):
    x, y = pos
    ...
```